# Slick slider not autoplaying on blogger website

Tags: jquery, html, css, blogger, slick.js

So I downloaded and customized **[Slick Slider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)**. I got it working perfectly how I need locally.

However when I added it to a blog website on blogger.com it works okay.. But then I noticed the **auto play is not working** and the **"Nav dot buttons" at the bottom of the slider are missing.**

But everything works fine locally... And I was unsuccessful in identifying the problem in dev tools.

Could I get a second pair of eyes on this? **The slider I am speaking about is located under the main logo**. U can drag it left and right with a mouse but it does not auto play.

## **[See Here](https://thepaletails.blogspot.co.uk/)**

Thanks!

Comment: The nav dots are not displaying and its not auto playing... Pretty clear what the issue was from my description.

Comment: So if you go into dev tools and search "dots" u will find the html dots but they are not displaying... 

And the slider is not auto player. U can drag it left and right with your mouse or finger on touch screen though

Comment: Its just a fashion blog on blogger.com lol but no worries.

Comment: oo lame sauce. I get to smoke weed with my boss ;)

Answer (score 0):

I ASSUME that this slider came with the template. If so, search

```html
$('.homepage-carousel').slick({
```

and Add the following code in its properties

```html
autoplay: true,
```

I hope it works.
Pardon me if it doesn't. I am a newbie, but I have extensively used that same template.